# How to change Azure AD User invite email template and Accept invite link, Currently it's allowing text only, can we make like HTML

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

- I am trying to customise the Azure AD user invite, Is it possible to make it with HTML or hyperlinks at least for long links.
- I want to edit the Accept Invitation link, currently it's redirecting to https://myapplications.microsoft.com.
  [image]

There is option to update the redirect URIs in Azure portal, but I don't see any specific URI for invite email related.

Comment: Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) doesn't provide direct options within the Azure portal to customize the invite email template or the accept invite link format. However, you can achieve some level of customization using Azure AD B2B (Business-to-Business) collaboration features and PowerShell scripting.